# POM file for Camel

Tags: maven, apache-camel, pom.xml

I am trying to compile the sample app for Camel and having problems with the POM file. The POM includes the following yet I am getting error (compile time) that the dependency is missing.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

```
 <properties>
        <camel.version>2.16.3</camel.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Do a maven clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Update the repository (File->Settings->Build->Build Tools->Maven->Repositories->Update-Ok) and reimport the project into IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

please add output which contains error.

Most probably, you could have problem with:

1. you forgot define repository

   problem with proxy .m2/settings.xml

   something bad with your firewall, try remove current artifact from .m2/repository/org/apache/camel

Answer (score 0):

Try :
Right click project > Maven > Update Project (Select Force Update)